# proving if player 1 has a pure optimal strategy, player 2 should as well

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

## Problem:

Prove that if in a matrix game 2x2 if the player 1 has a pure optimal strategy, so has player 2

## Attempt:

### Given:

We know that player 1 has pure optimal strategy, meaning:
$$P(x, \overline{y}) \leq P(\overline{x}, \overline{y}) \leq P(\overline{x}, y) $$
**Do we actually know that?**

I thought about expressing $P(x,y)=-Q(x,y)$ but nowhere it's said that it's an antagonistic game, but then I found this theorem:

If we knew that there is a saddle point, we would know that, there is a price and that:
$$P(x, \overline{y}) \leq v \leq P(\overline{x},y)$$
Meaning that there is dual solution:

$$\begin{cases}
    v -> min\\
    P(i,y) \leq v \\
    y \in Y
  \end{cases}
$$

$$\begin{cases}
    v -> max\\
    P(x,j) \geq v \\
    x \in X
  \end{cases}
$$

## Question:

The Problmem is ... do we actually know that we have antagonistic game or a seddle point, just by knowing that Player 1 has pure strategy? How can we prove this ?

Comment: Maybe it's just too long since I've looked at game theory, but I thought a matrix game was zero-sum by definition.  If not, how can you describe the payoff functions with one matrix?

Comment: @saulspatz I think so as well, it should be, I just want to validate this statement as it's nowhere to be said

Comment: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Matrix_game

Comment: ok ... so I have to prove the von Neumann's minimax theorem ?